# cypress semantic-ui-react menu tests - not getting content of menu options

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, browser-automation

I am writing some tests here on a component that uses semantic-react-ui using cypress js to test with.

Here is the div containing the elements I wish to test on:

```
<div data-testid="images-count" class="customize-row images-count">
   <h3 data-testid="option-name-8" class="option-name">Font Size</h3>
   <div data-testid="font-select" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true" class="ui active visible selection dropdown option-input images-select" tabindex="0">
      <div class="text" role="alert" aria-live="polite">Medium</div>
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <div class="menu transition visible">
         <div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">Small</span></div>
         <div role="option" aria-checked="true" aria-selected="true" class="active selected item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">Medium</span></div>
         <div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">Large</span></div>
         <div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">Extra Large</span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is a small test that I have done so far for elements within that div:

```
    cy.get("[data-testid=images-count]").within($result => {
       cy.findByRole("alert").should("have.text", "Medium");
       cy.get(".icon").should("be.visible");
       cy.get(".menu").should("not.be.visible");
       cy.get("[data-testid=font-select]").click();
       cy.get(".menu").should("be.visible");
    });
```

I attempted to get the options from the menu into an array, then validate them against another array:

```
cy.get('.menu').then(options => {
  const actual = [...options].map(o => o.value)
  expect(actual).to.deep.eq(['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra Large'])
})
```

However this returns the list of divs and not the actual test contant I am looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get options passed into `.then(options => ...)`, you will need to be more specific in the `cy.get()` selector.

An element's text content would be returned from the `o.innerText` property instead of `o.value`.

```js
cy.get('.menu .item').then(options => {
  const actual = [...options].map(o => o.innerText );
  expect(actual).to.deep.eq(['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra Large']);
})
```

---

You can be a bit more concise by getting all the text in one string

```js
cy.get('.menu .item')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', 'SmallMediumLargeExtra Large')

// OR

cy.get('.menu')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', '\n  Small\n  Medium\n  Large\n  Extra Large\n')
```

With these, be careful of the possibility of non-option text within the menu, as it just grabs all the text it can find within the selector you give it.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do options.map without the array and spread op? I think the way you're doing it would just insert an array into another array...

If its an issue with options coming back as undefined or empty, just put in an

```
const actual = options && options.length > 0 ? options.map(o => o.value) : []
```